# Error when sorting array list using a comparator in Java

Tags: java

Dear fellow programmers,
I have been trying to implement a sorting system to sort images by its height plus the y coordinate. However every time I try to run it I get an error after a few seconds.

> Error

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(Unknown Source)
```

> List which gets sorted:

```
ArrayList<Image> list = new ArrayList<Image>();
list.sort(imageSorter);
```

> Sorter:

```
public static final Comparator<Image> imageSorter = new Comparator<Image>() {

        // indexes used to calculate the sorting \\
        float yIndex_0, yIndex_1;

        public int compare(Imageimage_0, Imageimage_1) {

            yIndex_0 = image_0.y + image_0.height;
            yIndex_1 = image_1.y + image_1.height;

            if(yIndex_0 < yIndex_1) {
                return -1;

            }

            return 1;

        }
    };
```

I have tried many things for trying to fix this including the part below but with no success.

> Part i tried to add to fix this problem.

```
if(image_0 == null || image_1 == null) {

    if(image_0 == image_1) {
        return 0;
    }else if (image_0 == null) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

If you know any methods to try to fix this problem, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your comparison method will return `1` even if `yIndex_0` and `yIndex_1` are equal. This means a>a, which violates the reflexive property of equivalence relations. The method should instead return `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because your comparison is not transitive. E.g., if `A` and `B`is equal, comparing `(A,B)` will tell you that `A` is greater while comparing `(B,A)` will tell you that `B` is greater. Try and add a case for `yIndex_0 == yIndex_1` that returns `0`.

Comment: I added the function but it causes the program to crash even faster.

Comment: I now added the function at the end of the sorter and now it seems to be working all fine, thankyou for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one more condition in Comparator yIndex_0 == yIndex_1 return 0.

```
public static final Comparator<Image> imageSorter = new Comparator<Image>() {

    // indexes used to calculate the sorting \\
    float yIndex_0, yIndex_1;

    public int compare(Imageimage_0, Imageimage_1) {

        yIndex_0 = image_0.y + image_0.height;
        yIndex_1 = image_1.y + image_1.height;

        if(yIndex_0 == yIndex_1) {
            return 0;
        } elseif(yIndex_0 < yIndex_1) {
            return -1;

        }

        return 1;

    }
};
```